# OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns) for table with hyphens in name

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset

I'm reading some Excel data using ADO, and want to acquire some OpenSchema column values.

My connection string (which successfully opens the connection) is:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:[my
>   path].xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;";

I can happily open the AdSchemaTables recordset and get the table name:

```
Set tablesRs = conn.OpenSchema(AD_SCHEMA_TABLES)

Do While Not tablesRs.EOF
    tbl = tablesRs.Fields("TABLE_NAME")
    /../
Loop
```

And for a table with a name like `Sheet1$`, I can also happily read my column data:

```
Set colsRs = conn.OpenSchema(AD_SCHEMA_COLUMNS, Array(Empty, Empty, tbl))
```

My problem is that the name of one of the sheets contains hyphens, eg "16-11-2018" and this seems to throw a 3251 error. I've tried with and without inverted commas "'16-11-2018'" and square brackets "[16-11-2018]", but the former throws 3251 and the latter returns an empty recordset.

I know the data is good because if I copy the sheet to a different workbook with a generic sheet name, my code works fine. So I'm assuming my problem is related to that sheet name.

Is there a way of dealing with this sheet name?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in single quotes, so you are effectively looking to use:

```
Array(Empty, Empty, "'16-11-2018$'")
```

as the second argument.

Comment: I tried that and am still getting a 3251 error. Do you think the problem is still related to the sheet name?